# Objective C - converting currentDate to an integer

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to convert today's date into the following format as an integer:

yyyymmdd

For example 20th Sept 2014 to be 20140926

The following code works in all respects other than 09 for September becomes 9 without the 0. How do I fix this:

```
int todaysDate = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d%d", (int)currentDate.year, currentDate.month, currentDate.day]integerValue];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int todaysDate = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%02d%02d", (int)currentDate.year, currentDate.month, currentDate.day]integerValue];
```

I assumed you'd like a leading zero for the day as well. Didn't format the year.

Comment: Brilliant - thank you. Do I assume that when it becomes October (i.e. 10) the leading 0 will not be there?